# Error: Column does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, quoted-identifier

I have been able to link PostgreSQL to java. I have been able to display all the records in the table, however I unable to perform delete operation.

Here is my code:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
String stm = "DELETE FROM hostdetails WHERE MAC = 'kzhdf'";
pst = con.prepareStatement(stm);
pst.executeUpdate();
```

Please note that MAC is a string field and is written in capital letters. This field **does** exist in the table.

The error that I am getting:

SEVERE: ERROR: column "mac" does not exist

Answer (score 10):

When it comes to Postgresql and entity names (Tables, Columns, etc.) with UPPER CASE letters, you need to "escape" the word by placing it in "". Please refer to [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) on this particular subject. So, your example would be written like this:

`String stm = "DELETE FROM hostdetails WHERE \"MAC\" = 'kzhdf'";`

On a side note, considering you are using prepared statements, you should not be setting the value directly in your SQL statement.

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
String stm = "DELETE FROM hostdetails WHERE \"MAC\" = ?";
pst = con.prepareStatement(stm);
pst.setString(1, "kzhdf");
pst.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: @user2128318 Very happy to have helped.

Comment: If the value in the query is static, then it is perfectly fine to do it without a parameter (although then you don't really need a `PreparedStatement`)